# How to create interface from fields of class?

Tags: typescript

I have a class for model with typed fields and static `generate` method that returns these fields based on passed object:

```js
export class Message {
  _id!: string
  type!: 'foo' | 'bar'

  static generate(properties): X {
    return {
      _id: properties.test.id,
      type: properties.test._type_
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to somehow generate X (result of `generate` method) based on fields types in class, like this (but without typing fields twice — inside class and inside type alias):

```js
type X = {
  _id: string
  type: 'foo' | 'bar'
}
```

Is there a way to tell TypeScript to check result of `generate` method based on class fields? Or inherit class fields types from X alias?

Comment: [What's wrong with returning `Message`...?](https://tsplay.dev/wEBYbN)

Comment: @caTS it throws an error: `Type '{ _id: "test"; type: "foo"; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Message': keys, entries, toJSON, isValid, and 8 more.`

Comment: @VityaSchel Your comment suggests that you want to generate interface that excludes methods / functions from the class. Does [OmitFunctions type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AMQK4DsDGwEHt0DOAPACoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFM1ANoAKUC6UA1hCFwAzKCSgBDAqI4BdKBAAewCOgAmUtFhz4oAfijoIANwgAnKAC4o7GVZKzGAX0aNMAG0lSAshAIFxAObQ9ExQAPoIqgCEVgTAptwBjMygkDFQAORCuLgZUAA+mQBG4qYZLqHAuABSBPgAFACUsfGJtMksphDAqKY8AET9ANwdzgwdceI4mFBBhqZTEPVgpriQpji+VuLoIM2wiCgY2HiERD5+gRAUISxQXT197aF3EapWK2tmmwQAdMpxX6RAA0HTuqQgH1W6x+-18wF+YQhYTBUDGzDGY0YQA) work for you? If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the `: X` off your `generate` definition, Typescript will infer the return type. Is this actually what you are looking for?

By default, it's going to generate an record type with the keys (_id and type) mapped to `any`. To fix this, you can do something like this:

```
 static generate(properties) {
    return {
      _id: properties.test.id as number,
      type: properties.test._type_ as string
    }
  }
```

There may be an easier way to get the types in there, but this is what I have done to avoid duplication.

Don't forget, you'll be able to use the `ReturnType` macro to use this type elsewhere.

Comment: I'm looking for return type of generate, I want to check if `properties.test._type_` is string and if `properties.test.id` is number. Actually instead of simple strings and numbers I have type aliases in real code so I don't want to type all types again

Comment: Yes, the type inference of TS will do this.